# jquery draggable within fixed position draggable

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

im stucking on 2 jq drag/drop problems and would need help to fix that.
see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/perea1/898wZ/11/

1) i have a draggable ("clone") within a fixed position draggable "dragcontainer". As long as the container is not dragged, the drop position (offset) in "listitem" is correct.
Once the container was dragged to another position, the drop position becomes incorrect.

```
<div class="dragcontainer">
    <div class="handle">drag me here</div><br />
    <div class="clonesort">clone me / sortable</div>
    <div class="clone">clone me / nested</div>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <div class="listitem">list item 1</div>
    <div class="listitem">list item 2</div>
</div>
```

.) drag "clone me nested" to "List item" (drop position is correct)
.) now drag the container ("drag me here")
.) drag "clone me nested" to "List item" (drop position is incorrect)

2) appended elements are not droppable
a) drag "clone me sortable" to "List item" -  the new list item must be droppable, but is not
b) same for drag "clone me nested" - the new clone must be droppable, but is not

best regards,
peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you  have this problem:
Get the offset position of the fixed position draggable and add the top/left offset to drop position

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery [`draggable()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Draggable&redirect=no#option-containment) containment option.